# APC won't cache files in zend other that index.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, apc, opcode

I installed APC and I'm trying to use it for opcode caching with zend framework.

The problem is that the only file that gets cached is index.php

My APC config:

```
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 32M
apc.optimization = 0
apc.num_files_hint = 512
apc.user_entries_hint = 1024
apc.ttl = 0
apc.user_ttl = 0
apc.gc_ttl = 600
apc.cache_by_default = 1
apc.slam_defense = 0
apc.use_request_time = 1
apc.mmap_file_mask = /tmp/apc-accountname.XXXXXX
apc.file_update_protection = 2
apc.enable_cli = 0
apc.max_file_size = 2M
apc.stat = 1
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.report_autofilter = 0
apc.include_once_override = 0
apc.rfc1867 = 0
apc.rfc1867_prefix = "upload_"
apc.rfc1867_name = "APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS"
apc.rfc1867_freq = 0
apc.localcache = 1
apc.localcache.size = 512
apc.coredump_unmap = 0
apc.stat_ctime = 0
```

**UPDATE**

It actually doesn't cache any file included or required.

Comment: "the only file that gets cached is index.php" - how did you get that?

Comment: How is PHP running, is it running as a CGI where PHP is spawned on each call?